# Hyperlink in grid Dynamics 365 F&O

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a list page with a grid to which I would like to add buttons in order to route to a details page, in the same way that it is done by the standard application on the form SalesTableListPage.

I see here that this is a form with the pattern 'List Page' and then for the grid fields the properties 'Hyper Link Data Source' and 'Hyper Link Menu Item' are both set:

[image]

When I recreate my form in the same style as the SalesTableListPage however, I cannot see these properties for the fields added to my grid. (I made sure to choose a property with the same data type as SalesIdAdvanced)

What am I missing for these properties to be available?

Answer (score 1):

If you set your "Form Template" (which is under Form properties) as List Page and when you drag and drop fields from DS, you will get Hyperlink DataSource and Hyperlink Menu Item under Grid level field properties. Refer SalesTableListPage form in D365 F&O.

answered here last comment: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum/268529/how-to-add-hyperlink-to-the-field-in-grid?pifragment-109373=2#responses